# Delphi - Print to pdf with Microsoft Print To Pdf

Tags: delphi, pdf, printing, spool

I got a thread that create pages beetween `printer.beginDoc`, and `printer.endDoc` and on `thread.onTerminate` i call `shellExecute` to open the pdf flie, and it is not complete.

When i open it after 10 seconds, everything is ok.

Is there a way to know when the pdf file is ready. I suppose that it should finish printing? Or maybe printSpooler?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community: The question is perfectly clear to me. If you print a document the usual Pascal way, with `BeginDoc ... EndDoc`, to a virtual printer, typically (probably always) the output file isn't created at the time `EndDoc` is called. It will be completed soon afterwards.

Comment: @PekiCa: "to open the pdf [file]": How do you get the file name from the virtual printer's Save As dialog?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand

 ```printer.PrinterIndex := Printer.Printers.IndexOf('Microsoft Print to PDF');

  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DeviceMode);

  Printer.SetPrinter(Device, Driver, fileName, 0);```

Where ```fileName``` is a string with file address

Comment: @KJ I need to do monitoring to know when to open the file because there is no way to know when printing is done. There is no error. The link you posted is great!  I think I will find an answer there.